# Is it possible to simultaneously select item in combobox and insert into different columns of database table?

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I am using C#.net. my query is:  I have multiple items in my combobox, when i select 1st item , it should get inserted in column1 of database table,when i select 2nd item of the same combobox, it should get inserted in 2nd column of database table and so on.. 
How can I write the code for the same.

Comment: Are developing windows app or web ?

Answer (score 1):

as you haven't provided any of your effor so the best  i can do is to write a pseudo code for you.

```
string columnName = string.Empty;
if(myComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
  columnName = "column1";
else if(myComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
  columnName = "column1";

string myValue = "assign your value here";
string insertStatement = "insert into myTable("+columnName+") values(@param1)";

using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    sqlCon.Open();  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStatement,sqlCon);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = myValue;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectedIndex change event to capture the record selected and based on the index you can write the switch statement to insert in proper column

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this for solve your problem :-

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex ==1)
  {
   // Your other code Column 1
  }
  if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex ==2)
  {
   // Your other code Column 2
 }
}
```

May be help you

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the selected index to the database. You need to check the index value to set the value to the appropriate column from the database itself.